# Trouble finding the limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having trouble with this question. I tried numerous ways of approaching this problem and i jut cant figure it out. I got a feeling I have to multiply top and bottom by (1+cos(6x), but I'm not sure. Can someone help me?

lim((1-cos(6x))/(sin(5x)) as x approaches 0.

Comment: You should trust your feeling.

Comment: @vadim123: Not sure how that helps OP; this still yields an indeterminate form.  Ultimately, some further manipulation, either as in Clement C.'s solution, or L'Hôpital, is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you know the limit of
$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ at $0$ (it is $\frac{1}{2}$) and the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at $0$ (it is $1$). Then, you can write, for $x\neq 0$,
$$
\frac{1-\cos 6x}{\sin 5x} = \frac{1-\cos 6x}{(6x)^2}\cdot \frac{(6x)^2}{5x}\cdot \frac{5x}{\sin 5x}.
$$
Given the first paragraph, each of the three factors has an easy-to-compute limit.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow what you have been thinking i.e. multiply the numerator and denominator by $(1 + \cos 6x)$. We thus have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos 6x}{\sin 5x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos 6x}{\sin 5x}\cdot\frac{1 + \cos 6x}{1 + \cos 6x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos^{2} 6x}{\sin 5x}\cdot\frac{1}{1 + \cos 6x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}6x}{\sin 5x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}6x}{(6x)^{2}}\cdot\frac{(6x)^{2}}{5x}\cdot\frac{5x}{\sin 5x}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}1\cdot\frac{36x}{5}\cdot 1\notag\\
&= 0
\end{align}